# Javascript array into function not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, addition, field

I have used this website a lot for research etc and find it extremely useful.

I have been developing a little bit of code that will get a list of input id names and then add there values together using javascript/jquery.

This is what I have so far - it might be well off the mark as I am still a novice.

So far the code gets the names of the inputs fine.  It also does the calculation fine but when I put the array into the "var fieldnames" the calculation stops working?

When I copy the array out (after putting it into an input) and pasting it into the "var fieldnames" it works fine.

The issue seems to be that the array doesnt pass over to the "var fieldnames" correctly??

Here is the code from the page - it puts the array into the inputs at the bottom for investigation purposes only but the calculation doesnt work unless you put the input names in manually!

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head><body>




<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function getTotal(oForm)
  {
var arrayOfIDs = $('.myClass').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
var test = (arrayOfIDs.length ? "'" + arrayOfIDs.join("','") + "'" : "");

 document.getElementById("sum").value = test;

  var field, i = 0, total = 0, els = oForm.elements;
  var fieldnames = [test];

  document.getElementById("sum1").value = fieldnames;

  for (i; i < fieldnames.length; ++i)
  {
  field = els[fieldnames[i]];
  if (field.value != '' && isNaN(field.value))
  {
  alert('Please enter a valid number here.')
  field.focus();
  field.select();
  return '';
  }
  else total += Number(field.value);
  }
  return ' ' + total;
  }
</script>




<div id="listing">
<form>
<table>
<td>8065020</td>
<td>2012-04-10</td>
<td>household</td>
<td><input    class="myClass" id="pay47" type="text" name="pay47" value="38.45"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8065021</td>
<td>2012-04-10</td>

<td>household</td>
<td><input   class="myClass" id="pay48" type="text" name="pay48" value="37.4"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8065022</td>
<td>2012-04-10</td>
<td>household</td>
<td><input   class="myClass"  id="pay49" type="text" name="pay49" value="375"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8065014</td>
<td>2012-04-04</td>

<td>household</td>
<td><input type="text"  class="myClass"  id="pay50" name="pay50" value="06"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8065015</td>
<td>2012-04-04</td>
<td>motorprotect</td>
<td><input type="text"  class="myClass"  id="pay51" name="pay51" value="01"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8065011</td>
<td>2012-03-06</td>

<td>household</td>
<td><input type="text"   class="myClass" id="pay52" name="pay52" value="55"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8065012</td>
<td>2012-03-06</td>
<td>household</td>
<td><input type="text"  class="myClass"  id="pay53" name="pay53" value="56"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td/>

<td>household</td>
<td><input type="text"   class="myClass" id="pay54" name="pay54" value="56"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td/>
<td>household</td>
<td><input type="text"  class="myClass"  id="pay55" name="pay55" value="52"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td/>
<td>household</td>

<td><input type="text"  class="myClass"  id="pay56" name="pay56" value="53"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td/>
<td>household</td>
<td><input type="text"  class="myClass"  id="pay57" name="pay57" value="55"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8065001</td>
<td/>
<td>landlord</td>
<td><input type="text"  class="myClass"  id="pay58" name="pay58" value="5"/></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>8065002</td>
<td/>
<td>landlord-basic</td>
<td><input type="text"   class="myClass" id="pay59" name="pay59" value="59"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8065003</td>
<td/>
<td>household</td>
<td><input type="text"  class="myClass"  id="pay60" name="pay60" value="5"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>8065004</td>
<td/>
<td>household</td>
<td><input type="text"  class="myClass"  id="pay61" name="pay61" value="5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8065005</td>
<td/>
<td>household</td>
<td><input type="text"   class="myClass" id="pay62" name="pay62" value="5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>8065006</td>
<td/>
<td>landlord-basic</td>
<td><input type="text"   class="myClass"  id="pay63" name="pay63" value="64"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8065008</td>
<td/>
<td>household</td>
<td><input type="text"   class="myClass" id="pay64" name="pay64" value="5" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8065010</td>

<td/>
<td>business-basic</td>
<td><input type="text"  class="myClass"  id="pay65" name="pay65" value="10" /></td>
</tr>
</table>


<input id="total" type="text" name="total" value="" readonly="readonly" /> 
<input type="button" value="Get Total" onclick="total.value=getTotal(this.form)" />
<br /><br />
<input name="totalpay" id="sum" type="text" />sum<br />
<input name="totalpay" id="sum1" type="text" />sum1
</form>
</div>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try including your script after the body tag?

Comment: `fieldnames` is an array holding just one element, the string value of the `#sum` input. This is presumably not what you intended.

Comment: The code is below the opening body tag? and fieldnames is holding test which is the array of fields?

Comment: I took the liberty of creating a simplified version of your code, highlight of the invalid fields, and focus the first one: if you find it of value, use it :) http://jsfiddle.net/hvTsS/

Comment: thanks a lot for all the help, it is much appreciated!  I was just wondering how I could go about making this calculation automatically rather than having to press the 'Get Total' button?

Comment: You could add a change event handler to the class, and recalculate on that.  I would ask another question so you would get better/good feedback on that new question.

Comment: Thanks Mark - I managed to get it working using a click trigger for the button on document ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Replace the line

```
var test = (arrayOfIDs.length ? "'" + arrayOfIDs.join("','") + "'" : "");
```

By

```
var test = (arrayOfIDs.length ? arrayOfIDs.join(",") : "");
```

2- Replace

```
var fieldnames = [test];
```

By

```
var fieldnames = test.split(",");
```

3- Replace

```
field = els[fieldnames[i]];
```

By

```
field = document.getElementById(fieldnames[i]);
```

What i did here is only correct you code to resolve your problem, but i am covinced that you can do this in a more easiest way.

Comment: I do understand that this is not the best way to do it - after getting replies ot the messages and maybe it is worth me doing a little more research into making it more concise but thanks for your help - this answer worked a treat. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly and you just want to add up your values, while provideing basic validity check, your code is way to complicated. Frameworks like jQuery provide you with means to do this much simpler.

Instead of looping through all input elements, getting their id's and then looping through them again, just do it once.

```
var getTotal (oForm) {
    var sum = 0;
    // loop through all inputs with class "myClass" inside oForm
    $("input.myClass", $(oForm)).each(function (index, value) {
        // add up all values that are non empty and numeric
        if (value !== "" && !isNaN(value)) {
            // parse the value
            sum += parseFloat(value, 10);
        } else {
            // show an alert, focus the input and return early from $.fn.each
            alert("Please enter a valid number here!");
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // set the value of 
    $("sum").val(sum);
}
```

This was written from the top of my head but should work fine.

Comment: The code is below the opening body tag? and fieldnames is holding test which is the array of fields.

Thanks Torsten but when I implement this code it just keeps bringing up the alert message?

Comment: Some of the values are not integer.